# How to queue jobs in gearman so that they are strictly processed one at a time, in the order they were submitted?

Tags: php, gearman

Is this the default behaviour for gearman or do I have to specify it as a parameter?

I am using php and I am using gearman to queue up a large amount of mysql queries, kind of using gearman as a transaction manager. It's crucial that a job isn't processed before a job that was submitted earlier.

Also, will adding extra workers increase performance even though the jobs have to be done one at a time? A job consists of several mysql queries.

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour is to take them one at a time in the given order.

Adding a second worker will change that. It will still process the queue in the same order, but there is nothing to say that one worker will not be able to execute several jobs in the same time as the first does one.